# Ckeditor on IE 8 - Table cell select

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

http://ckeditor.com/demo

When I go to the demo page in IE 8 and click on the Table button in the editor, accept the defaults. Now when I click in one cell and drag to highlight multiple cells, it doesn't highlight the cells. The reason I am trying to highlight the cells is to use the right-click context menu to merge/split/etc.

This works fine on Firefox 27. But as per http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKSource-Graded-Browser-Support IE 8 should get A grade support so I am not sure why even the demo page itself is not working.

Without this, a very important function in table editing (multiple cell operations like merging) becomes impossible.  Is there a workaround?

Are there some settings to tweak? What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is Internet Explorer's bug or in different words - missing feature. When a table is empty, the selection is invisible. CKEditor fixes hundreds of browsers bugs or "missing features", but it's not possible to fix such one in a way that won't break something else.

But you don't need to select multiple cells to merge them. There are options like "Merge right" or "Merge down", so even when having collapsed selection, it is possible to merge cells. This is the best possible workaround that CKEditor might propose.

Comment: Well it doesn't work even when the cells are not empty. Yes the Merge left/right are good workarounds for 2 cells but if I want to merge a block of 5x5 dragging and selecting them is much faster. Thanks for responding.